# uname -r showing linux-image version that is unsigned

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, initramfs

My boot menu was full and then I tried to purge some older version of linux kernel with `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-...` command. As initram-fs wasn't throwing error again and again I also tried some online solutions. Not sure whether I messed up anything. Now when I am checking my current kernel in use, I see the version name that is basically unsigned. It will make problems, right? How can I be out of this? I am very beginner in these hardcore things. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

> It will make problems, right?

If you are using the secure boot, the kernel won't boot.

see: [How to sign things for Secure Boot](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot)

> How can I be out of this?

You can reinstall a signed kernel if you want. To know the recently removed packages, use `history | grep "apt purge"` then reinstall the removed kernel:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-*.*.*-**-generic
```